# Visual Basic, make application only open in a specific folder

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way I can make a Visual Basic .net app open only if it's located in a specific folder/path or if it contains a certain element inside the folder? 
Thanks.

Comment: Well technically your app needs to be running in order to evaluate what its current path is. So you can check the path of the current executing assembly at startup, and throw an exception if that's not what you want to enforce... which... is rather annoying, but you do your thing! So yes, it can be done, with `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` being your important building block. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use this to check for folder or file in application path:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'check if folder exists
        If Not IO.Directory.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\yourdirname") Then
            Application.Exit()
        End If

        'check if file exists
        If Not IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\yourdirname\yourfile.ext") Then
            Application.Exit()
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, On load event:

```
If not Application.StartupPath() = "C:\" then
    Application.Exit()
End if
```

Comment: Thank you, although I was looking for something that would require the Application to close if there isn't a specific Named folder where the Application would be placed.